# Http 404 not found tomcat 8.0 server

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, tomcat8, eclipse-mars

I have installed tomcat 8 server on eclipse and changed the port to 9009.I started the server and on visiting *localhost:9009* it says 404 not found.
On changing the server location to the ***second option in the image***,it worked.Can someone throw light on these ***three options*** ?
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4axlh.png)

Comment: Show us the log, please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ghNWTnha .Posted in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

By default eclipse forgets to Copy root folder to eclipse workspace tomcat installation files. Hence it doesn't contains tomcat homepage files which in turn throws resource not found 404. But second option will take control of tomcat installation folder. Hence it works.

First option: webapps will be available in Eclipse workspace.
Second option: webapps will be available in tomcat installation directory.
Third option: webapps will be available in custom directory which we have given.

To make first option to work do this.
        Copy root folder of tomcat installation dir under ../webapps to /wptwebapps of eclipse workspace something like org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps (or .../tmp1/wtpwebapps if you already had another server registered in Eclipse).

Then restart tomcat server in Eclipse. Homepage of tomcat will be loaded.

Comment: which option should be used in dev environment ??

Comment: _I will recommend first/third options by myself for dev env_ because eclipse will have seperate workspace for tomcat webapps instead of using tomcat base installation directory.